# Counting number of values in a time range

Tags: excel

I have a table as follows:

```
Task    Name    Start Time   End Time
 1       A       09:00:00    10:00:00
 2       B       09:10:00    14:00:00
 3       A       10:00:00    13:00:00
 4       B       10:30:00    12:30:00
```

I want to find out how many tasks a person is working simultaneously. So in the above example, A is working on 2 tasks but not at the same time. B is working on 2 tasks too but he started task 4 while working on task 2. So my output should show that at a given time, B is working on 2 tasks together. Is this possible?

([Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvS2r.png))

Comment: Are your times always sorted by start time?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given only 2 tasks each for A and B, try out this formula (Only works for 2 tasks each)

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(AND(C4>INDEX(B:D,MATCH(B4,$B$1:$B3,0),2),C4<INDEX(B:D,MATCH(B4,$B$1:$B3,0),3)),AND(D4>INDEX(B:D,MATCH(B4,$B$1:$B3,0),2),D4<INDEX(B:D,MATCH(B4,$B$1:$B3,0),3))),"Multiple tasks","Single task"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I've shown just 2 tasks as an example. The real dataset i'm working on has about 1000 rows with about 30 people. How can I implement this across such big data?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will find the last time before the current and test whether there is overlap:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MEDIAN(AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$1:C1/(($B$1:B1=B2)*($C$1:C1<C2)),1),C2,INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($C$1:C1)/($B$1:B1=B2),1))-TIME(0,1,0))=C2,"Overlap",""),"")
```

[image]